# parsing command-line arguments from proc/pid/cmdline

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse the command-line arguments of **another program** (which is an emulator) inside my program using `system()` command and the emulator's `pid`. Unfortunately using both file read and `cat`, the output is not well-formatted, so I can not really get the data. `cat` on  command line shows the file contents with spaces removed, the whole string sticked together, and using `ifstream`, it only shows the name of the program (the first argument I guess). Anyone has got any ideas?

The format of the arguments is like this:

```
sudo ./src/yse6 -w -f tracefiles/capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt -at=eth1 -an=eth0
```

and eventually I need to show the same string as formatted above.

Here is what I've done so far: (`ExecCommand()` gets a command, runs it in command-line and returns the result as `string`. `Secondary()` tries to get the file contents using file reader.)

```
std::string ExeCommand(const char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}

void secondary(string addr){

        ifstream file(addr.c_str(),ios::in);
        if (file.good())
        {
            string str;
            while(getline(file, str))
            {
                istringstream ss(str);
                cout<<str<<endl;
                char num[50];
                while(ss >> num)
                {
                    cout<<num;
                }
            }
        }else{
            cout<<"no file exists."<<endl;
        }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if ((string) argv[1] == "-q") {
        string pid=ExeCommand("ps -A | grep 'yse6' | awk '{print $1}'");
        if(pid==""){
            cout<<"No YSE emulator is running."<<endl;
        }else{
            pid=pid.substr(0,pid.size()-1);
            cout<<pid<<endl;
            string addr="cat /usr/bin/strings /proc/"+pid+"/cmdline";

            cout<<addr<<endl;
//          secondary(addr);

            const char * c = addr.c_str();
            string config=ExeCommand(c);
            //get the config
            cout << config<<endl;
        }//end of else
    }
}
```

Comment: The contents of that file are NULL-separated, not space-separated...

Comment: yes, I know that. I should just play with the file reader option I guess, right?

Comment: Read the entire contents of the file into a buffer (PAGESIZE bytes should be sufficient), then scan the data read for zero bytes. Except for the last one (which you can tell because `read()` tells you how many bytes it actually read), the byte after each zero byte is the beginning of the next string...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the good info. I'm not much familiar with C++ functions, it could be best if you could help me with the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, but with more error checking, should be a good start (this is more C than C++, aside from the `cout` bit):

```
const int BUFSIZE = 4096; // should really get PAGESIZE or something instead...
unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // dynamic allocation rather than stack/global would be better

int fd = open("/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY);
int nbytesread = read(fd, buffer, BUFSIZE);
unsigned char *end = buffer + nbytesread;
for (unsigned char *p = buffer; p < end; /**/)
{ cout << p << endl;
  while (*p++); // skip until start of next 0-terminated section
}
close(fd);
```

In particular, `open()` and `read()` should be checked for error conditions, but I haven't shown that part... This may also fail in extreme cases where your command line is > 4096 characters long, or if for some other reason, `read()` doesn't read the file in one call, which shouldn't happen in current `/proc` implementations, but is not always guaranteed...

Comment: Fair enough. What library should I include for that? I guess `stdio.h`, which is already there. But for `int fd = open(addr, O_RDONLY);` it says:
`‘O_RDONLY’ was not declared in this scope`
and `‘open’ was not declared in this scope` and

Comment: Generally, `man foo` will tell you what headers you need to `#include` in order to use `foo()`... In the case of `open()`, on my current Linux system, that means `<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>`, and `<fcntl.h>`. It may differ on other systems, and the C++ headers are somewhat different, too...

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix would be to read the bytes and then iterate over to remove the null terminated character with spaces. This is a C based implementation. The error conditions haven't been checked though.

```
char *name = (char *)malloc(MAX_SIZE);
char procfile[MAX_SIZE];
sprintf(procfile, "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);
int fd = open(procfile, O_RDONLY);
int size = read(fd,name,sizeof(procfile));
close(fd);
for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++){
 if(!name[i]) name[i] = ' ';
}
```